# 80 columns with autofill-mode doesn't return automatically

Tags: auto-fill-mode

I have set autofill to 80 with `C-x f` and autofill-mode is enabled (I see `Fill` in the modeline), but it doesn't return automatically after 80 characters.

How can I make it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `auto-fill-mode` docs:

> When Auto Fill mode is enabled, **inserting a space at a column
>   beyond `current-fill-column'** automatically breaks the line at a
>   previous space.

So if you e.g., type a continuous string starting from column 1 to column 100, it will not break at 80 even if you set `fill-column` to 80. However, if you enter a space at any point after column 80, any text you type after that should go on the next line automatically.

## Update:

The OP was having this issue in `c-mode`, which contains the variable`c-ignore-auto-fill` which is a

> List of contexts in which automatic filling never occurs.
>   If Auto Fill mode is active, it will be temporarily disabled if point
>   is in any context on this list.

By default (for me) it is set to `(string cpp code)` which means that it will ignore `auto-fill-mode` in the following contexts:

> string  -- inside a string or character literal
>
> cpp     -- inside a preprocessor directive
>
> code    -- anywhere else, i.e. in normal code

If you put `(setq c-ignore-auto-fill nil)` in your init file, it should work as you want it to. However, I don't have any experience in the c language, and am not sure if there will be consequences to this setting. I assume, because of these defaults, that there may be some consequences...

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work, it continue to write after, even if I put more than one words after.

Comment: What kind of buffer are you using it in? If it is a `text-mode` buffer or one related to it, you might have to call `toggle-text-mode-auto-fill` as well. I tested things out starting emacs with the `-Q` option, setting `fill-column` to 80 with `C-x f` and then turning on `auto-fill-mode`. This was all done in a scratch buffer in `lisp-interaction-mode`

Comment: It's a C buffer. Why using -Q ? I saw it's quick mode but I don't know what it brings.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto The `-Q` option will load emacs without your init file and site-wide startup file among other things. This allows you to kind of start emacs with a blank slate. If it works fine with `-Q` or `-q` the issue is probably caused somewhere in your init file

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto If you are in `c-mode`, try customizing the variable `c-ignore-auto-fill`. This is probably what is causing your issue

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto in `c-mode` I was able to reproduce your issue. I solved it in the way explained in the update to my answer above.

Comment: Also, with regards to the `-Q` option, see this: http://www.lunaryorn.com/2015/11/29/reproduce-bugs-in-emacs-Q.html Stumbled upon it just now, and it looks like an interesting and related read (related to `-Q` that is)

Comment: Thanks !
I needed to customize `c-ignore-auto-fill`, now it works !